# String filtering! shell linux

Tags: linux, string, shell

```
patt= "apk"
 if [[ "$1" =~ $patt ]]; then
      echo "[-] Name of aplication type WITHOUT .apk extension!!!!!"

else
  some code...
```

Hey guys... i have a little problem with how to be sure to files vith extesion.apk cant be typed in!! Thanks

And this doesnt work at all!
    `ad.sh: apk: not found
                       ad.sh: [[: not found`

Comment: Please edit your question and see how to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: `patt= "apk"` attempts to run a command named `apk` with the variable `patt` set to an empty string.

Comment: ...and if `[[` isn't working, then I guess you're using some shell other than bash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `apk` as a regex (strings as `tapkey` will match).

You'd better extract the extension and `echo` your message if it's equal to `apk`:

```
ext="apk" # no space before and after = sign
if [[ ${1##*.} == "$ext" ]]; then
  echo "[-] Name of aplication type WITHOUT .apk extension!!!!!";
fi
```